# Live debugging a Spring boot project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, spring-boot, eclipse-mars

I am trying to create a Spring boot based MVC application using eclipse.

I created a starter template from spring's starter website and i have imported the maven package into eclipse.

I created a controller and a view and I am able to run the application by going to "debug as" or "run as" and selecting Java Application and then selecting the spring boot application main method from the list.

However with this approach, Eclipse does not seem to auto build my changes in my java classes nor the changes in my template views. (I use Thymeleaf btw) on the fly even though "auto build" is switched on in eclipse.

This forces me to stop the application in eclipse and re run the application for every small change i make and its very difficult.

Is this the only way on eclipse or is there a better way for eclipse would auto build the java and template files on the way so that I can code and debug simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse is most likely compiling because that's what Eclipse does, but maybe you need to install the [dev tools](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html) so that you get live reloading enabled.

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks.

Comment: As swordfish mentioned for Gregg: it is awesome. Works properly. Where else could I have gotten the information in the first place?